# How do I show entire array in Label within ListView using Eval and string.Join?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, eval

How do I show an entire array of varying length in a Label of a List view?
I have tried following

```
<td>
    <asp:Label ID="MyArrayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# string.Join(",",Eval("MyArrayLabel")) %>' /> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the `Eval` back to an Array. In this example the Array is a `List<string>`, but it can be any IEnumerable.

```
<asp:Label ID="MyArrayLabel" Text='<%# string.Join(",",Eval("MyArrayLabel") as List<string>) %>' />
```